# Get Visual Studio Code terminal history

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the VS Code terminal, I can navigate with up & down arrows through all of the commands I used these last months, **but what if I want to see the full terminal history of commands?.**

Is it in a specific file? I read it is strored in a local buffer, but how to look into it?

Oh, and writing "history" only returns today's session history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS Code uses an external shell. On Windows, this is PowerShell, and the command you are looking for is:

```
cat (Get-PSReadlineOption).HistorySavePath
```

On linux, it uses bash, so the command will simply be:

```
history
```

Comment: Thank you very much! To save it in a file, I added:
 
    `cat (Get-PSReadLineOption).HistorySavePath > vsc_history.txt`